# (Discord.py) How do I make a dare 21 game? i need to take inputs in the form of numbers, like "1 2 3" (max 3 numbers) and make it turn by turn?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a discord bot where I am trying to make the game "21 dares" (see this link for info on that [https://www.wikihow.com/Play-21-Dares][1])

how do I take inputs turn by turn? I tried making a list of players using

> players = await msg.reaction.users().flatten()

but how do I make it so that it's turn by turn?

next, I need to check the inputs, like, the first player is only allowed to say a maximum of 3 numbers, and the second player has to start after the first's third number.
basic idea being,

Player A: “1, 2, 3.” Player B: “4, 5.” Player C: “6, 7, 8.” Player D: “9.” Player E: “10, 11, 12.” Player A: “13, 14, 15.” Player B: “16, 17.” Player C: “18.” Player D: “19, 20.” Player E: “21.” In this instance, Player E was forced to say “21.”
Player A: “1.” Player B: “2, 3, 4.” Player C: “5, 6, 7.” Player D: “8, 9, 10.” Player A: “11.” Player B: “12, 13, 14.” Player C: “15.” Player D: “16, 17, 18.” Player A: “19.” Player B: “20.” Player C: “21.” In this instance, Player C was forced to say “21.”
Player A: “1.” Player B: “2, 3, 4.” Player C: “5, 6, 7.” Player D: “8.” Player E: “9.” Player F: “10, 11, 12.” Player G: “13, 14.” Player H: “15, 16.” Player A: “17, 18, 19.” Player B: “20.” Player C: “21.” In this instance, Player C was forced to say “21.

this is my code so far. pls help me I've been trying to make this work for 3 days

````
    async def tod(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        '''21 truth or dare game'''
        the_author = ctx.author
        channel = ctx.channel
        if user is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Truth or Dare game", color=discord.Colour.orange(),
                                  description=f"{the_author.mention} is inviting anyone to play truth or dare! \n\nType `accept` now to accept the challenge and begin a game with them.")
        elif user != the_author and not user.bot:
            embed = discord.Embed(title=" truth or dare", color=discord.Colour.orange(),
                                  description=f"{the_author.mention} is inviting anyone to play truth or dare! \n\nType `accept` now to accept the challenge and begin a game with them.")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="You can't invite yourself or a discord bot to a game!")
        
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("✅")
        

        import time
        time.sleep(10)
        players = await msg.reaction.users().flatten()
        check_list = []
        current_count = []
        def check(message):
            list = message.split(' ')
            for element in list:

                element = int(element)
                check_list.append(element)

            range_list=list(range(min(check_list), max(check_list)+1))
            if check_list == range_list:
                for element in current_count :check_list.append(element)
                check_list.clear()

        await self.bot.wait_for( 'message', check=check, timeout=60)```

I'm quite new to discord.py, so any small tips are also appreciated.

  [1]: https://www.wikihow.com/Play-21-Dares
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_message` to react on a sent message. From this event you receive an object of type `Message`.  With the attribute `author` you can get the member, which sent the message. You can now compare the id's of member and the current player. With the `content` attribute of `Message` you can check if the message is valid or not.
You can read the documentation yourself [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)

To check which players turn it is I suggest you simply create an counter, which increases each time you get an valid message. You compare the Member-ID of an user with the ID of `player[counter]`.

**Edit to comment of @Dhravya Shah:**
I would check it like this (I didn't test the code, but the concept would be this):

```py
client = discord.Client()
count = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if players[count] == message.author:
        #Check if message is valid
        if messageIsValid: #placeholder variable
            #Save  the answer to an array or similar
            count += 1
```

Comment: can you please show an example how to check player turn

Comment: yes, it took a while but I finally figured it out; Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i figured it out. I cycled through the playerlist using `itertools.cycle()` I couldn't figure out how I iterate through the particular element of the list again,so I simply made it so that the player who does a mistake loses the game
This is my entire code, hopefully it helps someone else

````py
@commands.command(name='21dares', aliases= ['truth_or_dare'])
    async def tod(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
        '''21 truth or dare game'''
        the_author = ctx.author
        channel = ctx.channel
        if user is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Truth or Dare game", color=discord.Colour.orange(),
                                  description=f"{the_author.mention} is inviting anyone to play truth or dare! \n\nType `accept` now to accept the challenge and begin a game with them.")
        elif user != the_author and not user.bot:
            embed = discord.Embed(title=" truth or dare", color=discord.Colour.orange(),
                                  description=f"{the_author.mention} is inviting anyone to play truth or dare! \n\nType `accept` now to accept the challenge and begin a game with them.")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="You can't invite yourself or a discord bot to a game!")
        
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)

        
        playerlist = []
        check_list = []
        count_list = []
        current_count = 0

        def checkConsecutive(l):
            return sorted(l) == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1))

        def check(message):
            return True
        
        while True:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=check)
            if msg.content == 'accept':
                await ctx.send(f'{msg.author.mention} accepted! type `start` before 60 seconds to start')
                playerlist.append(msg.author)

            elif msg.content == 'start' and len(playerlist)>=2:
                await ctx.send(f'Game started!Start by typing `1 2 ..`')
                
                for player in itertools.cycle(playerlist):
                    embedlost = discord.Embed(title=f"{player} lost! choose `Truth or Dare?!`")
                    await ctx.send(f"{player.mention}'s turn!")
                    def check1(message):
                        if message.author == player:

                            return True
                    n = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=check1)
                    if n.content == 'cancel' or n.content =='stop': break
                    if n.author == player and n.author != self.bot.user:
                        listn = n.content.split(' ')
                        for element in listn:
                            element = int(element)
                            check_list.append(element)

                        if current_count >= 21:
                            
                            await ctx.send(embed= embedlost)

                            break
                        elif check_list[0] == current_count+1:
                            if checkConsecutive(check_list)==True:
                                for element in check_list : count_list.append(element)
                                current_count = count_list[-1]
                                check_list.clear()
                                await n.add_reaction('✅')
                            else :
                                await ctx.send('Numbers not consecutive! YOU SPOLIED THE GAME! YOU LOSE!')
                                await ctx.send(embed=embedlost)
                                check_list.clear()
                                break
                        else:
                            await ctx.send(f'Dude you have to start from {current_count+1}! YOU SPOLIED THE GAME! YOU LOSE!')
                            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            
            elif msg.content == 'start' and len(playerlist)==0 or len(playerlist)==1:
                await ctx.send("Can't start, less than 2 players")    
            elif msg.content == 'cancel':
                await ctx.send('Game Cancelled')
                break```
#Its probably not the ideal code, but it works as I want it to, so I guess its fine
````